# Native-boot VHD deployed operating system does not hibernate

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, vhd, boot-to-vhd

Not several months ago I deployed a native boot VHD running Windows 10 OS, I was not using it a lot, not until now I use it frequently and sometimes I wish to save my current tasks by hibernating the system instead of putting it to sleep or switching it off.

However I seem not to be able to achieve this, when I try to enable hibernation on the system it refuses and I get the following error:

```
An internal system component has disabled hibernation
Boot from VHD
```

Is there any explanation to this, or another workaround to enable hibernation of native boot OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, [native VHD boot never supports hibernation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/gg318048(v=ws.10)#limitations).

> **Limitations**
>   **Hibernation.** You cannot hibernate an operating system that runs on a VHD. However, sleep functionality is available.

Put the VHD on a SSD to have faster boot times.